# How can we refer to a child of a commit?

Tags: git

Given a branch name or a tag `name`, we can refer to its parent by `name~1`. Can we refer to one of its children in some way?

Thanks.

Comment: In a way similar to that a commit can have multiple parents, and use `name ~n`

Comment: @jonrsharpe A child can have multiple parents (e.g., a merge commit). The problem is that Git simply does not store parent-to-child links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [chepner said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313542/1256452), the information is not directly available, as Git only stores *backwards* links.  A parent commit always exists when its child is created, but its children do not exist when the parent is created.  Once a commit has been created, nothing about it can ever be changed, so there's no way to hook it up *to* its children.

Nonetheless, if you have a *direction* in mind, you *can* find the children of some commit *in that direction*.  Here's what I mean: suppose the graph looks like this:

```
          B--D--E   <-- branch1
         /
...--o--A
         \
          C--F--G   <-- branch2
```

And, suppose you have the name or hash ID of commit `A` in your paws at the moment.  You can find the hash ID of commit `B` by searching from `A` in the "branch1" direction, and the hash ID of commit `C` by searching from `A` in the "branch2" direction.  To do this, use:

```
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --ancestry-path A..branch1
```

which will list out the hash IDs for commits `B`, `D`, and `E` in that order.  Replace `branch1` with `branch2` to get `C`, `F`, and `G` in that order.

Be aware that if the graph looks like this:

```
          B--E   <-- branch1
         /  /
...--o--A--D
         \
          C   <-- branch2
```

you could get *either* `B` *or* `D` first, in the `A..branch1` direction.  To check for such situations, instead of (or in addition to) using `--topo-order` and/or `--reverse`, collect *all* the commits along this ancestry path, and for each such commit, check *all* that commit's parents:

```
ahash=$(git rev-parse A^{commit}) # in case A is a branch or tag name, for instance
for hash in $(git rev-list --ancestry-path $ahash..branch1); do
    if git rev-parse $hash^@ | grep -q $ahash; then
        echo $hash is a child of $ahash
    fi
done
```

(this code is untested).

Comment: Thanks. How do you draw those lovely diagrams?

Comment: How can I find all the children of a commit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423808/how-can-i-show-the-hash-ids-of-all-the-commits

Comment: @Ben: by hand, alas. There are some OK graph-drawing tools for graphics, but few if any for text.

Answer (score 1):

A Git repository is represented as a DAG (directed, acyclic graph) of commits. Each commit includes one pointer to each of its parents, but no information about what commits have *it* as a parent. That's why you can only refer to the parents *of* a commit (`name~1`, `name~2`, etc), not the commits that *have* `name` as a parent.

(Most commits have a single parent, but a merge commit is an example of a commit with 2 or more parents, depending on how many branches were involved in the merge.)