# How can I show the hash IDs of all the commits?

Tags: git

This from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314490/10082400 can show only the hash IDs of selected commits

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path $ahash..branch1
```

This can show all kinds of information about all the commits:

```
git log --all
```

How can I show only the hash IDs of all the commits? Thanks.

Comment: `git log --all` shows the hash IDs. I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Please explain what is in the linked content, to make your question self-contained. Do not expect readers to have to follow links to understand what you are asking.

Comment: `git rev-list --all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--all` option to `rev-list`:

```
> git rev-list --all
c26b9ea61d21822e965a91096111cf6b16b526cd
726602e78b21c0b7541159f58003bd36398071e7
f581634e4cc2d29d15a0dfbea5d119e10babc847
124ba39cf50af622e4f51d712095dc304d2a69fc
3ff00334516c044a1bceb90234b569412300814a
...
```

You can also use the `--pretty` flag to control exactly what `git log` outputs, although in this case my `abbrev` setting shortened the sha1's -- `--no-abbrev` would make it output the same as `git rev-list --all`:

```
> git log --pretty=%h --all
c26b9ea61
726602e78
f581634e4
124ba39cf
3ff003345
...
```

Read up the "Pretty Formats" section of `git log --help` or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log for more details.