# Why does `git rev-parse HEAD^2` not work?

Tags: git

Why does the following (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314490/10082400) not work? How can I make it work? Thanks.

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD^2
HEAD^2
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: "make it work", please start by explaining what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^2` means "the second parent", not "the parent of the parent". Maybe your HEAD only has one parent? Use `~2` for a grandparent.

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for details.

Comment: *`^2` means "the second parent"* the second parent **of a merge  commit**, not "the parent of the parent" which is `^^` or `~~` or `~2`.

Comment: @choroba Didn't you confuse `^2` with `~2`? It then would have been the great-parent rather than the second parent, yes. Ow, you beat me to it, phd ;-)